# Json decode in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

here I use this code in my local host

```
$fromdata= $_POST["data"];
$fromValue=json_decode($fromdata);
$patientid=  $fromValue->patientid;
$patientname= $fromValue->name;
```

its working fine... if i use

```
print_r($fromdata);
```

it print the following format

```
{"patientid":"55","name":"Sow"}
```

. the same code is used in wordpress the `print_r($fromdata);`  return `{\"patientid\":\"16\",\"name\":\"Ravindran\"}` this. and unable to get value

how to get value from this object
thanks

Comment: What do you you get when you execute `print_r($_POST["data"]);`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to [a longstanding quirk](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21767), you'll need to first use [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the extra slashes that WordPress adds to the request's JSON string.

The pre-stripped data looks something like this:

```
$json_string = '{\"patientid\":\"16\",\"name\":\"Ravindran\"}';
```

So to convert it, you'll need to do something like this:

```
$object = json_decode(stripslashes($json_string));
```

Or if you instead want an associative array:

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($json_string), true);
```

Comment: yep.  That fixed it.