# Properly escape javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, json, object

Given an object: `{"key":"pairs","are":"fun"}` that is echoed into a variable like `const foo = <?php echo $bar ?>;`. What is the proper way to escape the object? I've tried `encode_json` which escapes all the double quotes `{\"key\":\"pairs\",\"are\":\"fun\"}` disallowing the object to render. I have also tried `esc_js` which converts the double quotes to `& quot;`. How do i properly escape the object and return the object to `foo`? The out should be `{"key":"pairs","are":"fun"}` escaped of any malicious content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json decode in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305643/json-decode-in-wordpress)

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: @JackBashford the output should be `{"key":"pairs","are":"fun"}`. Just escaped of any malicious content.

Comment: @alt-rock, so, what kind of malicious content? If you merely need valid JSON, just feed a key-value array or object (not a string) to `wp_encode_json` (i.e. have it build the json string for you.)

Comment: @EPB content that could be subject to XSS

Comment: @alt-rock, so if you have `wp_encode_json` create your JSON string (instead of making the JSON string yourself as you appear to be doing here) you can avoid `XSS` at this part as you can generally rely on it doing a good job of creating well-formed JSON. Then depending on how you are using your values, you can use other filters depending upon how the values are going to be used. Say `esc_html` for text that's going into a label. -- If this sounds like the general direction you're needing, I can write out a proper answer with example code and such.

Comment: Good explanation so far, @EPB. However I do build the string from `$myArray = [
  [ 'key' => 'pairs' ],
  [ 'are' => 'fun' ],
]` then i map the array to an object. the object is what is shown in the question description. The full object will then be iterated over in Javascript. Before it hits the javascript i wanted to escape the value. If you could write the best practice here out for me i'd greatly appreciate it and accept your answer.

Comment: @EPB is it safe for me to do this? `const mySafeObject = JSON.parse(<?php echo wp_json_encode($myObject) ?>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `wp_json_encode` to produce the JSON string itself, the output where you assign the JSON to a JavaScript variable in the browser should be reasonably safe. The `wp_json_encode` function will escape the characters that might otherwise allow someone to inject code at the point of assignment.

However, you also have to consider how your values in the key/value pairs will be used. If you're expecting an integer, maybe run the value through `intval` or if you are expecting plaintext that you're injecting into the page later, perhaps run it through `esc_html`.

For example:

```
<?php
$map = [
        'key' => 'pairs',
        'are' => '"; I document.write(\'fun trying to break out\')',
        'i_am_expecting_plaintext' => esc_html('<a href="evillinkhere">Hello</a><script>evilscript();</script>'),
        'i_expect_an_integer' => intval("90i"), 
        'some_html_allowed' => wp_kses('<a href="http://nisamerica.com/">here</a><script>dangerous();</script>', ['a' => array('href'=>array())]),
];
?>

<script>const foo = <?php echo wp_json_encode($map, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;</script>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<script>const foo = {
    "key": "pairs",
    "are": "\"; I document.write('fun trying to break out')",
    "i_am_expecting_plaintext": "&lt;a href=&quot;evillinkhere&quot;&gt;Hello&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;script&gt;evilscript();&lt;\/script&gt;",
    "i_expect_an_integer": 90,
    "some_html_allowed": "<a href=\"http:\/\/nisamerica.com\/\">here<\/a>dangerous();"
};</script>
```

Addendum:

The reason `wp_json_encode` was giving you `{\"key\":\"pairs\",\"are\":\"fun\"}` before is that you were providing it a string that was already in JSON-notation. What `wp_json_encode` does is take native PHP variables and escape them as JSON. It's a pretty thin wrapper around `json_encode` really.  My suggestion above is really to just produce the map in PHP, and feed *that* to the encode function instead of making your string representation and then trying to make it safe.